# Is there a way to optimize Parallax scrolling for chrome?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I followed this tutorial:

http://www.weblinc.com/labs/jquery-parallax/

And in the end, my version (I only changed the image to have something else where the clouds were) was really laggy in chrome, but fine in fire fox, but the one on the site, the demo was fine, any reason for this?

not sure if you need code, say so if you do.

Comment: What's the image size of the one you replaced? The tutorial uses only two images of 5kb and 12kb respectively, which will unlikely to stutter due to the small sizes

Comment: hmm, one is 157kb one is 51kb, would this cause a big stutter though?

Comment: Not saying it would, but it could =) Also, check console whilst you scroll down, also use Chrome Tool's **Timeline** in particular to check if it's constantly having to 're-draw', if so - what?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using stellar.js for parallaxing, really simple to use: http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/